# External CSS works fine in Safari, but not in Firefox, Google Chrome, or Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, opera

So I have a simple html file with 3 external css files linked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh_CN">
<head>
    <title>some website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="style/reset.css" charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="style/shared.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="style/home.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="scripts/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <[end if]-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the css files works fine in Safari, but both Firefox and Google Chrome do not recognize all three css files. same issue in Opera.

I have double-checked the file paths, added charset="utf-8" where appropriate, and tried to clean caches, deleted all related files in Library of my user account and reinstalled both browsers. Still the same issue.

I am testing the website locally on a Mac with macOS 10.13.4 (17E202)

Safari version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.4)

Google Chrome version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Firefox version 59.0.3 (64-bit)

Opera version 52.0.2871.99

Some screenshots of the state of the inspector.

[Firefox Style Editor shows no style sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMPuZ.jpg)

[Google Chrome does not list css files as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuqFt.jpg)

As you can see, images and javascript files are just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

somehow change the three lines related with css files solved the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/shared.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/home.css">
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The type attribute should be specified as `type="text/css",` you have written `type="style/css"` change it and give a try and make sure your path is correct. check your browser if there are any 404 errors.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/shared.css" />
```

[Link For Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Comment: I need to have my eyesight checked out. Thank you!